# Select box on change value Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello everyone I would like to ask you a question with Laravel I am a student and just learn laravel. I have select box called leave type like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="leave_type" name="LEAVECODE">
                                    @foreach($leaveTypes as $leaveType)
                                        <option value="{{$leaveType-

>CODE}}">{{$leaveType->DESCRIPTION}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
```

And then after select change on leave type i have a function that select leave balance and then I want to show that leave balance on other text box.

```
public function getLeveBalance($leaveType,$empcode)
    {
            $leaveBalance = LeaveBalance::where('EMPCODE', $leaveType)->where('EMPCODE', $empcode)->where('INYEAR', '2017')->select('YTD')->first();
            return $leaveBalance;
    }
```

Comment: You question is unclear. Explain better what you want.

Comment: @Ni Ya question is unclear . Did you say for a combo box or for a dropdown list box ?

Comment: I think he wants to populate a text box with a value based on a select box option after processing.

Comment: You need to show ur route, other text box code.

Comment: Am really sorry could you show me the general concept.

Comment: Check below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your `head` section

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Add this AJAX script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#leave_type").change(function(){
        var selectOption = $("#leave_type option:selected").val();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            data: { selectOption: selectOption },
            url: '/abc',  //**Eg. URL in route
            success: function(response){
                if(response.success) {
                    $('#YourOtherTextBoxID').text(response.leaveBalance);
                    alert('success');
                }       
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Create a new route: Eg:

```
Route::post('/abc', 'YourController@funcName');
```

In `YourController`

```
public function funcName(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $leaveType = $request->selectOption; //**Your selected option

        // Do your DB processing
        // $this->getLeveBalance($leaveType, $empcode);
        // I assume $leaveBalance contains the value you need to show in OtherTextBox

        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'leaveBalance' => $leaveBalance]);
    }
}
```

Hope it's helpful.